# git filter-branch empty ident name (for <>) not allowed

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I need to use `git filter-branch` to re-write the history of a repository.
It seems that whatever the filter-branch command I try, it get stacked at one particular commit with empty identity name error.
For example:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f -R a_folder' -- --all
```

gives

```
Rewrite 1acdc25e87c404e974610b9517f62b4127c3ccac (1574/3846) (43 seconds passed, remaining 62 predicted)
fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed
could not write rewritten commit
```

If I then do:

```
git show 1acdc25e87c404e974610b9517f62b4127c3ccac
```

I get the following:

```
commit 1acdc25e87c404e974610b9517f62b4127c3ccac
Author:  <>
Date:   Mon Apr 27 19:31:42 2015 +0100

My Commit comment

diff --git a/file.cpp b/file.cpp
index 4db77cf..21b6fc0 100644
--- a/file.cpp
+++ b/file.cpp
@@ -50,6 +50,20 @@ E-mail: myEmail@mydomain.com

...Things I modified...
```

So it seems the problem lies in the fact that the committer name is empty. However if I look at the original commit that is being re-written here (thus with same comment and modifications) I see that name and e-mail of the committer are fine:

```
commit a1aa0612f35af3acf376938d355da0ecca6376a6
Author: My Name <myEmail@mydomain.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 27 19:31:42 2015 +0100

    My Commit comment
```

I am using git version 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.4.

Some time ago I have performed re-write operations on this same repository without problems. Only on a different machine, on which I do not have access any more.

Is it possible I am facing a bug on this git version? Any idea on how to troubleshoot the problem? Of course I tried to look on the web for help, but so far I could not find anyone facing anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

As a diagnostic step, you could try performing the same operation with the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/):

```
$ bfg --delete-folders a_folder
```

If the BFG fails as well, you've probably got some kind of corrupt git object in your repository that neither implementation of Git- neither C-Git, nor JGit (the Java library used by the BFG) can read.

If the BFG works, you may well have encountered a bug with git-filter branch that could be worth reporting to the git mailing list once you've verified that it happens in the latest version of Git (currently v2.17.0).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out that there were two identical commits with same comment and modifications, but one of the two was with empty identity.

`git log -grep='My commit comment'`

was returning only the one with correct identity so it was difficult to spot. I found it using `gitk` showing all branches and with commits sorted by date.